# HC-Sticky stops working after the page has scrolled so far

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, joomla, hcsticky

Bit of a newbie question here so please be gentle!

I have used HC-Sticky to create a sticky sidebar menu on my joomla webiste (http://www.youngmelksham.org.uk). An example can be seen on every page except the home page.

The menu stops 100px from the top as it is supposed to, but then after you have scrolled down the page some more the menu scrolls off the page.

It's like it works for about 150px then stops.

I use the following code to call the HC-Sticky

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#Mod{$module->id}').hcSticky({
        top: 100,
    });
});
```

Any advice would be really gratefully received.

Comment: Dd you remove that menu?

Comment: No, you can see it here - http://youngmelksham.org.uk/latest/latest-news.  If you scroll the page up you will see that the side menu stops for a little bit when it gets to the top, then scrolls off the page.

Comment: This is the error i am etting in Javascript console when i scroll This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning. Check this link           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098306/this-site-appears-to-use-a-scroll-linked-positioning-effect-this-may-not-work