# How to change css styles on scroll without delay

Tags: javascript, html, css

## Hi everyone,

I'm working on a side navigation menu for my churches website. You can see the demo here:

http://amightywind.com/sideNav/

However I have a problem. The navigation is supposed to work so when you scroll down the page past it's bottom the css changes to make it anchor and stop moving.

The problem is that the "anchoring" effect doesn't always work smoothly and will only be applied after you scrolled a few pixels past the bottom.

This causes the side bar to "jump" back into it's designed place.

I know this problem is probably caused by [asynchronous panning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098306/this-site-appears-to-use-a-scroll-linked-positioning-effect-this-may-not-work) (the browser delays repainting when scrolling to keep a smooth frame rate).

I was going to call this unsolvable, but then I saw firefox's [quantum browser page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/).

If you scroll down halfway, you will see a large pink box on the left that says "Firefox Quantum features".

The text changes positioning when you scroll into it similarly to how my side bar works. However 2 things are different.

## 1 there is no jump. It is perfectly smooth in every browser I tested.

I figured this could easily be because they are moving a smaller portion of content than I am, but....

## 2 when I inspect element I notice there is no css class/style change on the object when scrolled into it.

How is this possible? Is there a way to make this effect work without Javascript? Or at least more smoothly than I've done just listening to the window scroll event?

Any help would be much appreciated thank you!

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your website, nor is it anything you can control. You don't see a bounce on the Firefox page because there's additional content below the sidebar. But if you go to the bottom of the FF page and then try to scroll down, the whole page will bounce – as indeed would that pink box, if it were still in view at that point. Unless there's something else I'm missing, I don't think there's much you can do. FWIW, your sidebar seems very smooth to me. I wouldn't have thought anything was wrong if you didn't mention it.

Comment: @cjl750 Thank you for your input! Yes I see what you mean on the firefox page. I still wonder how they are making the text in the box scroll with you without changing any apparent css. Anyhow you are probably right that it's "good enough". I'm gonna play around with a few more things and will post if I find a better solution. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that the pink box uses `position: sticky` in the CSS, rather than toggling some class that makes it `position: fixed` with JavaScript. Also, there's a "current" class that gets added to/removed from the nav links in the pink box as you scroll past each section. So they are changing the CSS that way.

Comment: @cjl750 Oh That's a new one for me. I never heard of position sticky before. Wow I'm so behind! Browser support isn't that great for it yet though, but it's interesting the new css features ahead. Thank you for your time.