# What is the alternative to "scroll-linked positioning effect" to prevent performance issues?

Tags: jquery

I get the following warning in firefox

> This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!

The snippet I use is

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
    $('#share-bar').hide('slow');
  }
  else {
    $('#share-bar').show('slow');
  }
});
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: And why you think that’s an error? That’s more like a warning. Do you have any asynchronous panning effect in your website?

Comment: Only this one UItoTop https://gist.github.com/svizion/3241271 and yes I wrote it is a warning

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098306/this-site-appears-to-use-a-scroll-linked-positioning-effect-this-may-not-work)

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem here to javascript/jquery] `.onscroll()` then show the back to top button.

I solved this problem with a "switch boolean" and a timer:

(I had several solutions but it seems that this one is best)

With an ftm license (Free To Mankind license: show this script to anyone still programming):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="Constantin">
  <title>on scroll 2019</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <!-- the complete asyncron solution to manage "This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect",the console error you see from the browsers -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var sw=true;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if(sw){
            sw=false;
            setTimeout(function(){

            if ($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
                $('#gotop').show();
                sw=true;
            } else {
                $('#gotop').hide();
                sw=true;
            }

            }, 200);
        }
    });
$('#gotop').click(function(){
        //$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 100);
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
        return false;
    });
});//on ready

  </script>


<style type="text/css">
    #gotop {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: none;
    }
</style>
  <div id="gotop">GO TO TOP</div>
bla bla bla<br>not a lorem ipsum<br>only bla bla bla<br>bla bla bla<br>not a lorem ipsum<br>only bla bla bla<br>bla bla bla<br>not a lorem ipsum<br>only bla bla bla<br>bla bla bla<br>not a lorem ipsum<br>only bla bla bla<br>bla bla bla<br>not a lorem ipsum<br>only bla bla bla<br>bla bla bla<br>not a lorem ipsum<br>only bla bla bla<br>bla bla bla<br>not a lorem ipsum<br>only bla bla bla<br>bla bla bla<br>not a lorem ipsum<br>only bla bla bla<br>bla bla bla<br>not a lorem ipsum<br>only bla bla bla<br>bla bla bla<br>not a lorem ipsum<br>only bla bla bla<br>bla bla bla<br>not a lorem ipsum<br>only bla bla bla<br>bla bla bla<br>not a lorem ipsum<br>only bla bla bla<br>bla bla bla<br>not a lorem ipsum<br>only bla bla bla<br>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice to hear that! thank you ! pass this to your friends