# Navigation bar : position Absolute and Sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, sticky

I'm trying to make a navigation bar **that overlap** my header and stick to the top of the window on scroll.
It will start at `top: 45px` and stick at `top: 0` on scroll.

My first approach was to set it at `position: fixed; top: 45px` and change the value with JS on a `scroll` event. But Firefox gave me the warning about "*asynchronous panning*" discussed on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098306/this-site-appears-to-use-a-scroll-linked-positioning-effect-this-may-not-work).

I have been able to do it with a bit of CSS trickery, but I am wondering if there is a **simpler CSS way or a valid JS approach** to do this (not throwing a warning).

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1px;
  width: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 45px;
  overflow: visible;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-left: 50vw;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red;
}

header {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

main {
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav></nav>
</div>
<header>
</header>
<main>
</main>
```

Comment: what's the issue of the actual solution? and what you mean by *proper solution*?

Comment: I thought i'll get that comment :) I am not very experimented with css / js and the solution I came up with "felt" clanky. So I wondered if there was an appropriate JS way, or something I was missing. Anyway if it's good for you it's good for me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code and avoid using an extra container:

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  margin:45px auto -115px; /* 115 = height + margin-top */
  background-color: red;
}

header {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

main {
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<header>
</header>
<main>
</main>
```