# This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, scroll

I'm getting this warning in Firefox: "This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning."

I have a component in which some generated contents slides in as the element comes into the view on scroll. I'm doing this by adding a class when the element comes into the view.

I'm not sure what this warning means and How can I get rid of it. Thanks

[image]

This is the code for the component

```js
const FeatureCard = ({ src, alt, Graphic, title, text, direction, id, featuresList, Buttons }: FeatureCardProps) => {
    const imageContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
    const [imageContainerClassList, setImageContainerClassList] = useState<string>('img-container')
    const [renderedGraphic, setRenderedGraphic] = useState<string>('')

    const isInView = () => {
        if (imageContainerRef.current) {
            const rect = imageContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
            return rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= window.innerHeight
        }
        return false
    }

    const addInViewClass = () => {
        if(isInView()) {
            setImageContainerClassList('img-container in-view')
        }
    }

    const scrollHandler = () => {
        addInViewClass()
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
        addInViewClass()
        return (() => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
        })
    })

    return (
        <Styled className="row" direction={direction} id={id} flexDirectionColumnForImgContainer={featuresList && featuresList.length ? true : false}>
            <div
                className={imageContainerClassList}
                ref={imageContainerRef}
            >
                {Graphic ? <Graphic 
                    renderedGraphic={renderedGraphic}
                /> : null}
                {src ? <img
                    src={src}
                    alt={alt}
                    style={ featuresList && featuresList.length ? { transform: 'scale(.9)' } : {}}
                /> : null}
                {featuresList && featuresList.length ? (<ul>
                    {featuresList.map(
                        (feat, i) => <li key={i + feat}>{feat}</li>
                    )}
                </ul>) : null}
            </div>
            <div className="text">
                <h2>{title}</h2>
                {text}
                { Buttons ? <Buttons 
                    setRenderedGraphic={setRenderedGraphic}
                /> : null}
            </div>
        </Styled>
    )
}

export default FeatureCard
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098306/this-site-appears-to-use-a-scroll-linked-positioning-effect-this-may-not-work)

Comment: @KenBekov Thanks! I'm not able to understand it well i.e what should I do to make the warning go away.  I'm a junior dev Sorry for poor web dev skills.