# Bootstrap 4 navbar - first bottom of viewport and after scrolling sticky on top - in IE 11 not working

Tags: bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11, navbar, sticky

My matter has been described here countless times and some people seeking help have found a solution. Unfortunately, I have not yet found anything for my case. I am trying to resolve the following famous effect in IE 11 and down: Page finished loading, navigation in viewport is on postition bottom and when scrolling the page up, navigation is sticky on top. Like the template "twentyseventeen" in Wordpress. I work on Windows and use Xampp. It works with Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Opera. Not Safari, which isn't so bad as long as appels mobile version goes along. Also, the browsers of my mobile devices, such as Chrome and FireFox, have a good behavior, when I connect via the localhost IP. Even the Samsung browser gets everything right. Only the famous IE on my laptop doesn't work.

I am using Bootstrap v4.3.1 with jQuery v3.5.1: Does anyone have a solution please?

Thank you for taking action on my issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="12000">
                    <picture>
                        <source srcset="./images/body.jpg" media="(min-width: 1600px)">
                        <source srcset="./images/bg400x240.svg" media="(max-width: 400px)">
                        <img src="./images/bg2000x1200.svg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </picture>
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>sample heading</h5>
                        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="12000">
                    <picture>
                        <source srcset="./images/body.jpg" media="(min-width: 1600px)">
                        <source srcset="./images/bg400x240.svg" media="(max-width: 400px)">
                        <img src="./images/bg2000x1200.svg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </picture>
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>sample heading</h5>
                        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="12000">
                    <picture>
                        <source srcset="./images/body.jpg" media="(min-width: 1600px)">
                        <source srcset="./images/bg400x240.svg" media="(max-width: 400px)">
                        <img src="./images/bg2000x1200.svg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </picture>
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>sample heading</h5>
                        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>-->                                                                         <!-- If behaviour does not change, it can be removed.-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">                   <!-- Begin Main-Navigation -->
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./firstpage.html">Prólogo</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./secondpage.html">Manejo</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./thirdpage.html">Equidad de Género</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./fourthpage.html">TGyC</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
     <hr />
    <div aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <div class="container">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Home</li>
            </div>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="inside-banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row py-2">
                    <div class="col-md-3 d-flex align-items-center py-3">
                        <img src="images/backgroundImage.png" width="200" alt="logo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center py-3">
                        Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis
                        evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 d-flex align-items-center py-3">
                        Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis
                        evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="header">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="12000">
                            <picture>
                                <source srcset="./images/body.jpg" media="(max-width: 1600px)">
                                <source srcset="./images/bg400x240.svg" media="(max-width: 400px)">
                                <img src="./images/bg2000x1200.svg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                            </picture>
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h5>sample heading</h5>
                                <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="12000">
                            <picture>
                                <source srcset="./images/body.jpg" media="(max-width: 1600px)">
                                <source srcset="./images/bg400x240.svg" media="(max-width: 400px)">
                                <img src="./images/bg2000x1200.svg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                            </picture>
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h5>sample heading</h5>
                                <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="12000">
                            <picture>
                                <source srcset="./images/body.jpg" media="(max-width: 1600px)">
                                <source srcset="./images/bg400x240.svg" media="(max-width: 400px)">
                                <img src="./images/bg2000x1200.svg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                            </picture>
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h5>sample heading</h5>
                                <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!--<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>-->                                                                         <!-- If behaviour does not change, it can be removed.-->
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="container py-3 my-3">
        <h1>sample heading</h1>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluissetconcludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="banner2 my-3">
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center">
                <div>
                    <h1>Banner heading 2</h1>
                    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluissetconcludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container my-3">
        <h1>auto height content here</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="banner3 my-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="px-2 py-3">
                A div 944 x 322 px for: a div 800 px and 3 iframes
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <iframe width="100%" height="200px" src=""></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <iframe width="100%" height="200px" src=""></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <iframe width="100%" height="200px" src=""></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg3">
        <!-- noch leer -->
    </div>
    <div class="container py-3 my-3">
        <h1>sample heading</h1>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="banner3 my-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="px-2 py-3">
                A div 944 x 322 px for: a div 800 px and 3 iframes
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <iframe width="100%" height="200px" src=""></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <iframe width="100%" height="200px" src=""></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <iframe width="100%" height="200px" src=""></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg4">
        <!-- noch leer -->
    </div>
    <div class="container py-3 my-3">
        <h1>sample heading</h1>
        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="banner2 my-3">
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center">
                <div>
                    <h1>Banner heading 2</h1>
                    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <div>
                            <img width="250" src="images/10574244_687471241327450_1790403545201929663_n-758x491.jpg" />
                            <h6 class="mt-2"> The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <div>
                            <img width="250" src="images/10574244_687471241327450_1790403545201929663_n-758x491.jpg" />
                            <h6 class="mt-2"> The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <div>
                            <img width="250" src="images/10574244_687471241327450_1790403545201929663_n-758x491.jpg" />
                            <h6 class="mt-2"> The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <div>
                            <img width="250" src="images/10574244_687471241327450_1790403545201929663_n-758x491.jpg" />
                            <h6 class="mt-2"> The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="my-4">
                <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

        var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
        var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

        function myFunction() {
            if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
                navbar.classList.add("sticky")
            } else {
                navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  
  .carousel .item {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
  }
  
  #carouselExampleIndicators .carousel-indicators {
      bottom: 280px;
       z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .carousel-item .carousel-caption {
      bottom: 200px;
       z-index: 1;
  }
  
    /*@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
        from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        }
        to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
        }
    }

    @keyframes zoom {
        from {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
        }
        to {
        transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
        }
    }*/

.carousel-inner img {
  -webkit-animation: zoom 20s;
  animation: zoom 20s;
}

  #navbar{
      position: sticky;
      z-index: 2;
      bottom: 0;
  }
  
   hr {
    border-top: 2px solid #ff0000 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important; 
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
  
  .banner{
      background: url('./images/placeholder2000x1200.svg');
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 100%;
      font-weight: 700;
  }
 
  .content {
    padding: 16px;
  }
  
  .sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .sticky + .content {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  .banner2{
      height: 350px;
  }
  .h-100{
      height: 100%;
  }
  .bg3{
    background: url('./images/1024x698backgroundImage.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
  }
  .bg4{
    background: url('./images/820x558backgroundImage.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
  }
  .breadcrumb-outer{
      background: #e9ecef !important;
  }
  .select{
      width: 20% !important;
  }
  .dropbtn { 
    background-color: #4CAF50; 
    color: white; 
    padding: 16px; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    border: none; 
    cursor: pointer; 
} 

.dropdown { 
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block; 
} 

.dropdown-content { 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    background-color: #f9f9f9; 
    min-width: 160px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px  
        0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
    z-index: 1; 
} 

.dropdown-content a { 
    color: black; 
    padding: 12px 16px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    display: block; 
} 

.dropdown-content a:hover { 
    background-color: #f1f1f1 
} 

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { 
    display: block; 
} 

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn { 
    background-color: #3e8e41; 
}
```

By the way, if anyone is interested in this information: as you know, the Bootstrap carousel is already responsive, but not enough. For an image exchange for different viewports I have tried a few things, of which in the end only the variant in my html works properly. But the default settings don't let the images be zoomed on touch devices. One solution here was the zoom effect, which is actually an elegant variant, because it lasts the user a moment longer on the site.

Comment: You said,` in IE 11 and down: Page finished loading, navigation in the viewport is on position bottom and when scrolling the page up, navigation is sticky on top` is not working as expected. I try to test your sample code and it looks like it is working with the IE 11 browser. Please see my test result [here](https://imgur.com/a/xm2UEyt). I suggest you again try to run your sample code with IE 11 and see whether it works or not. If the issue still persists, can you please try to post the test result from your side? It can help us understand the issue properly. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I had the same results as @Deepak-MSFT – your code seems to work on IE11. You could get rid of a couple of CSS rules: #navbar (doesn’t seem to be needed) and #carouselExampleIndicators (puts the indicators in the middle of the image). I did notice one time that the carousel images hadn’t loaded right away, so the sticky height value was wrong (sticky depends on the images being loaded when the height is taken – could be a problem). If you’re going to support IE9, you’ll need the eligrey classList polyfill and the coliff bootstrap-ie8 / ie9 CSS. Also, your source code has the header div twice.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers and sorry that I'm replying late.

I have changed a little and commented everything a little more clearly. The main-nav and breadcrumb-nav are now enclosed in a parent div and sticky together. Now it works better, but I have this message: This site appears to be using a scroll-linked positioning effect. This might interact badly with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for more details and join the discussion about related tools and functions!

Would stickybits be a better solution?

Your opinions are very welcome. Many thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="first-carousel" class="container-fluid p-0">                                       <!-- Begin 1st Carousel -->
        <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="">    <!--still have to look for the right attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/listbox_role -->
                <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="12000">
                    <picture>
                        <source srcset="./images/placeholder2.jpg" media="(max-width: 1599px)"> <!-- Size-Test -->
                        <source srcset="./images/placeholder.jpg" media="(min-width: 400px)">   <!-- Size-Test -->
                        <img src="./images/placeholder.svg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </picture>
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>sample heading</h5>
                        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="12000">
                    <picture>
                        <source srcset="./images/placeholder2.jpg" media="(max-width: 1600px)"> <!-- Size-Test -->
                        <source srcset="./images/placeholder.jpg" media="(min-width: 400px)">   <!-- Size-Test -->
                        <img src="./images/placeholder.svg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </picture>
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>sample heading</h5>
                        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="12000">
                    <picture>
                        <source srcset="./images/placeholder2.jpg" media="(max-width: 1600px)"> <!-- Size-Test -->
                        <source srcset="./images/placeholder.jpg" media="(min-width: 400px)">   <!-- Size-Test -->
                        <img src="./images/placeholder.svg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </picture>
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>sample heading</h5>
                        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>                                                                                  <!-- End 1st Carousel-->
    **<div id="navbar-wrapper">**                                                               <!-- Begin Main-Nav -->
        <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
                <h5 class="text-white mb-0">bla bla bla</h5>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">Inicio</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="./firstpage.html">Prólogo</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="./secondpage.html">Manejo</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="./thirdpage.html">Equidad de Género</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="./fourthpage.html">TGyC</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </nav>                                                                              <!-- End Main-Nav -->
        <div aria-label="breadcrumb">                                                       <!-- Begin Breadcrumb-Nav -->
            <ol class="breadcrumb mb-1">
                <div class="container">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Home</li>
                </div>
            </ol>
        </div>
    **</div>**                                                                                  <!-- End Breadcrumb-Nav -->
    <div class="banner-ticket">                                                             <!-- Begin 1st Banner with Ticket -->
        <div class="inside-banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row py-2">
                    <div class="col-md-3 d-flex align-items-center py-3">
                        <img src="images/backgroundImage.png" width="200" alt="logo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center py-3">
                        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. 
                           Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum.Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 d-flex align-items-center py-3">
                        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. 
                           Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum.Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                                                                                  <!-- End 1st Banner ------- Ticket -->
    <div id="second-carousel" class="container-fluid p-0">                                  <!-- Begin 2nd Carousel -->
        <div id="carousel-2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="">    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/listbox_role -->
                <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="12000">
                   <picture>
                        <source srcset="./images/placeholder2.jpg" media="(max-width: 1599px)"> <!-- Size-Test -->
                        <source srcset="./images/placeholder.jpg" media="(min-width: 400px)">   <!-- Size-Test -->
                        <img src="./images/placeholder.svg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </picture>
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>sample heading</h5>
                        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="12000">
                    <picture>
                        <source srcset="./images/placeholder2.jpg" media="(max-width: 1599px)"> <!-- Size-Test -->
                        <source srcset="./images/placeholder.jpg" media="(min-width: 400px)">   <!-- Size-Test -->
                        <img src="./images/placeholder.svg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </picture>
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>sample heading</h5>
                        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="12000">
                    <picture>
                        <source srcset="./images/placeholder2.jpg" media="(max-width: 1599px)"> <!-- Size-Test -->
                        <source srcset="./images/placeholder.jpg" media="(min-width: 400px)">   <!-- Size-Test -->
                        <img src="./images/placeholder.svg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </picture>
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>sample heading</h5>
                        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>       
        </div>
    </div>                                                                              <!-- End 2nd Carousel-->
    <div class="bannerAfter2ndCarousel my-3">                                           <!-- Begin 2nd Banner -->
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center">
                <div>
                    <h1>Banner heading 2</h1>
                    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                                                                              <!-- End 2nd Banner -->
    <main>
        <div id="mainContent1" class="container my-3">                                      <!-- Begin 1st Topic-Content -->
            <h1>auto height content here</h1>
            <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. 
               Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum.Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
            <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. 
               Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum.Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>        
        </div>                                                                              <!-- End 1st Topic-Content -->
        <div class="banner-videos my-5">                                                    <!-- Begin 3rd Banner ----- Videos -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="px-2 py-3">
                    A div 944 x 322 px for: a div 800 px and 3 iframes
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="200px" src=""></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="200px" src=""></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="200px" src=""></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                                                                                  <!-- End 3rd Banner Videos -->
        <div id="mainContent2" class="container my-3">                                          <!-- Begin 2nd Topic-Content -->
            <h1>auto height content here</h1>
            <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. 
               Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum.Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
            <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. 
               Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum.Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>            
        </div>                                                                                  <!-- End 2nd Topic-Content -->
        <div class="banner-videos my-5">                                                        <!-- Begin 4th Banner ---- Videos -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="px-2 py-3">
                    A div 944 x 322 px for: a div 800 px and 3 iframes
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="200px" src=""></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="200px" src=""></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="200px" src=""></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                                                                                  <!-- End 4th Banner Videos -->
        <div id="mainContent3" class="container my-3">                                          <!-- Begin 3rd Topic-Content -->
            <h1>auto height content here</h1>
            <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. 
               Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum.Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
            <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. 
               Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum.Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>            
        </div>                                                                                  <!-- End 3rd Topic Content-->   
        <div class="bannerContent my-3">                                                        <!-- Begin 5th Banner -->
            <div class="container h-100">
                <div class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Banner heading 2</h1>
                        <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                                                                                  <!-- End 5th Banner -->
    </main>
        <div class="footer">                                                                    <!-- Begin Footer -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <div>
                                <img width="250" src="images/placeholder.jpg" />
                                <h6 class="mt-2"> The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <div>
                                <img width="250" src="images/placeholder.jpg" />
                                <h6 class="mt-2"> The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <div>
                                <img width="250" src="images/placeholder.jpg" />
                                <h6 class="mt-2"> The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <div>
                                <img width="250" src="images/placeholder.jpg" />
                                <h6 class="mt-2"> The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="my-4">
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                                                                                  <!-- End Footer -->
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="./fixed-navbar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


/* fixed-navbar.js*/

const nav = document.querySelector('#navbar-wrapper');
        const offset = nav.getBoundingClientRect();

        window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
            if (window.pageYOffset > offset.top) {
                nav.style.position = 'fixed';
                nav.style.top = 0;
            } else {
                nav.style.position = 'relative';
                nav.style.top = '';
            }
        });


/* CSS */
        
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------- Carousel ---------------------------------------------------------------*/                    

/*.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}*/

/*#carousel-1 #carousel-2 .carousel-indicators {    /* depence on the viewport of device */ 
    /*bottom: 280px;
    z-index: 1;
}*/
  
/*.carousel-item .carousel-caption {                /* depence on the viewport of device */ 
    /*bottom: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
}*/
  
.carousel-inner img {
    -webkit-animation: zoom 20s;
    animation: zoom 20s;
}
  
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
        }
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
        }
    to {
        transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
        }
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------- Main Navbar --------------------------------------------------------------*/
#navbar-wrapper {
    z-index: 111;
    width: 100%;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------- Breadcrumb-Nav ------------------------------------------------------------*/
.breadcrumb-outer {
    background: #e9ecef !important;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------- Banners -------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.bannerAfter2ndCarousel {                                           
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #e5ff80 !important;
}

.bannerContent {
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #e5ff80 !important;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------- Videos ---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.banner-videos {                                                                            
    background-color: #edceba;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------ Select Menu manejo.html------------------------------------------------------*/

/*.bg-upper{
    height: 100%;
   align-items: flex-end;

  }*/

.select {
    width: 20% !important;
}

.dropbtn { 
    background-color: #4CAF50; 
    color: white; 
    padding: 16px; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    border: none; 
    cursor: pointer; 
} 

.dropdown { 
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block; 
} 

.dropdown-content { 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    background-color: #f9f9f9; 
    min-width: 160px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
    z-index: 1; 
} 

.dropdown-content a { 
    color: black; 
    padding: 12px 16px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    display: block; 
} 

.dropdown-content a:hover { 
    background-color: #f1f1f1 
} 

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { 
    display: block; 
} 

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn { 
    background-color: #3e8e41; 
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I suggest you refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37100516/10309381) may give some clarity for the warning message that you are getting on your web page.