# Can anyone explain why Bootstrap button causes scroll-linked positioning effect warning?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

This is the error I get:

> This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning;

I finally found out why this is happening. It's caused by a Bootstrap button in a vue component.

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
    
<!-- language: lang-css -->

<button
 class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
 type="button"
 id="dropdownMenuButton1"
 data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
 aria-expanded="false"
>
 Select Build List
</button>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
 <li>
  <router-link to="link">Link</router-link>
 </li>
</ul>
```

At this moment, my solution is to just get rid of it. I've tried installing bootstrap@next for the newest version as well, but it's the same problem.

However, it doesn't explain why the problem is happening at all. I just want to understand why this is happening at all.

Comment: have you read about it? here is [an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098306/this-site-appears-to-use-a-scroll-linked-positioning-effect-this-may-not-work)

Comment: @wittgenstein, thanks! I did read that beforehand, but it doesn't really explain why Bootstrap was causing the issue. From what I can see, there is nothing that is scroll-linked from Bootstrap. On top of that, I another piece of code that uses transform but is not causing the issue.